# Where does entropy enter in Soft Actor-Critic?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, actor-critic-methods, soft-actor-critic

I am currently trying to understand SAC (Soft Actor-Critic), and I am thinking of it as a basic actor-critic with the entropy included. However, I expected the entropy to appear in the Q-function. From [SpinningUp-SAC](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/algorithms/sac.html), it looks like the entropy is entering through the value-function, so I'm thinking it enters by the $\log \pi_{\phi}(a_t \mid s_t)$ in the value function?

I'm a little stuck on understanding SAC, can anyone confirm/explain this to me?

Also, side-note question: is being a soft agent equivalent to including entropy in one of the object functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the answer I'll be using notation similar to the one from the SAC paper.
If we look at the standard objective function for policy gradient methods we have
\begin{align}
J_\pi &= V_\pi(s_t)\\
&= \mathbb E_{a_t \sim \pi(a|s_t)}[Q(s_t, a_t)]\\
&= \mathbb E_{a_t \sim \pi(a|s_t)}[ \mathbb E_{s_{t+1} \sim p(s|s_t, a_t)} [r(s_t, a_t) + V(s_{t+1})]]\\
&= \mathbb E_{a_t \sim \pi(a|s_t)}[ \mathbb E_{s_{t+1} \sim p(s|s_t, a_t)} [r(s_t, a_t) +  \mathbb E_{a_{t+1} \sim \pi(a|s_{t+1})}[ \mathbb E_{s_{t+2} \sim p(s|s_{t+1}, a_{t+1})} [r(s_{t+1}, a_{t+1}) + V(s_{t+2})]]]]\\
&\cdots\\
&= \sum_t \mathbb E_{(a_t, s_t) \sim \rho_\pi} [r( s_t, a_t)]
\end{align}
If you keep unwinding this $V(s_{t+i})$ you will get expected sum of rewards.
We can define soft state value as
\begin{align}
V(s_t) &= \mathbb E_{a_t \sim \pi(a|s_t)}[Q(s_t, a_t) + \mathcal H(\cdot|s_t)]\\
&= \mathbb E_{a_t \sim \pi(a|s_t)}[Q(s_t, a_t) + \mathbb E_{a \sim \pi(a|s_t)}[-\log(\pi(a|s_t))]]\\
&= \mathbb E_{a_t \sim \pi(a|s_t)}[Q(s_t, a_t) - \log(\pi(a_t|s_t))]
\end{align}
third equality comes from the fact that $\mathbb E_{a \sim \pi(a|s_t)}[-\log(\pi(a|s_t))]$ is nonrandom so its the same thing as if we are sampling over $\pi$ only once.

In maximum entropy framework objective function would then be 
\begin{align}
J_\pi &= V_\pi(s_t)\\
&= \mathbb E_{a_t \sim \pi(a|s_t)}[Q(s_t, a_t) - \log(\pi(a_t|s_t))]\\
&= \mathbb E_{a_t \sim \pi(a|s_t)}[ \mathbb E_{s_{t+1} \sim p(s|s_t, a_t)} [r(s_t, a_t) - \log(\pi(a_t|s_t)) + V(s_{t+1})]]\\
& \cdots\\
&= \sum_t \mathbb E_{(a_t, s_t) \sim \rho_\pi} [r(s_t, a_t) -\log(\pi(a_t|s_t))]\\
&= \sum_t \mathbb E_{(a_t, s_t) \sim \rho_\pi} [r(s_t, a_t) + \mathcal H(\cdot|s_t)]
\end{align}